# Disable password authentication for SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm looking for a way to disable SSH clients from accessing the password prompt as noted [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring).

I am unable to disable the `password:` prompt for *root login*. I have change the `sshd_config` file to read:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

and have also changed the permissions `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` and `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. What am I missing? Does this require I have a passphrase?

Verbose dump:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

#### File /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile    %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no
```

Comment: ssh -v user@server to get verbose output to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Both `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` have `PasswordAuthentication` -- stay sharp!

Answer (score 303, accepted):

In file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication no
```

Uncomment the second line, and, if needed, change yes to no.

Then run

```
service ssh restart
```

Comment: Many guides suggest changing ChallengeResponseAuthentication, PasswordAuthentication, UsePAM from yes to no on server. Successfully tested under Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: FYI, the systemd way to restart the service is:
   `systemctl restart sshd`
This is the default on newer Ubuntu.

Comment: How do I add new keys to the server, while password authentication is disabled? Surely there is a way to do this, without having to turn password authentication on, every time someone want's to add a key...

Comment: @Matthew Perhaps using `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: @iamyojimbo but you still need an authorized key to be able to connect and send one with that command.

Comment: @Matthew if you've disabled password login and haven't set up keys yet, then you aren't going to be able to remote in for that user. You'll need to directly make changes to the filesystem to let yourself back in, or physically log in with a keyboard and monitor...

Comment: Followed this with proper restart of sshd service, and I can still ssh with password from other devices

Comment: is there anyway to apply it only for root user?

Comment: A simple sed liner: `sed -i 's/#PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config |grep 'PasswordAuthentication no'`. To test before, leave the `i` flag. To test after, do `ssh -v host` and see if `debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey` is there.

Comment: @OriWiesel maybe you want this: `PermitRootLogin without-password`. However, if you put the solution from above, root should be included.

Comment: Outdated & bad answer, `AuthenticationMethods publickey` should be used instead.
Consult with the manual for detailed usage: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html

Answer (score 30):

Here's a one-liner to do this automatically

```
sed -i -E 's/#?PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

The `#?` is an extended regular expression that matches the line whether it's commented or not. The `-E` switch enables extended regexp support for sed.

Answer (score 16):

Run

```
service ssh restart
```

instead of

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

This might work.

Comment: This worked for me; any ideas why using init.d didn't?

Comment: Depends on your linux flavor... On gentoo both of them work for me.

Answer (score 8):

I followed these steps (for Mac).

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` change

```
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
#PasswordAuthentication yes
```

to

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Now generate the RSA key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

(For me an RSA key worked. A [DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) key did not work.)

A private key will be generated in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` along with `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (public key).

Now move to the *.ssh* folder: `cd ~/.ssh`

Enter `rm -rf authorized_keys` (sometimes multiple keys lead to an error).

Enter `vi authorized_keys`

Enter `:wq` to save this empty file

Enter `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Restart the SSH:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd
```

Comment: Can't you use [`touch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(command)) to create the empty file `authorized_keys`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes you can but why should you?

Comment: @Timo because it's fewer keystrokes

Comment: @jewbix.cube you do not need to create the file before, It will be created automatic. Try it.

Comment: @Timo Yes you are correct, but it wasn't clear that you were suggesting that from your previous comment.