# creating a openssh public key from private key

Tags: c, openssh, ssh-keygen

I am using ssh-keygen of openSSH to create public key from private key.

```
cmd1 = malloc(100);
snprintf(cmd1, 80, "./ssh-keygen -y -f %s > %s ",
        "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key", "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub");
rc = system(cmd1);
```

But the command always asks for a passphrase. Is there any way to disable asking passphrase ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH Disable Password Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898384/ssh-disable-password-authentication)

Comment: Why do you call it as `./ssh-keygen`?. There are only two possibilities. 1) Your key has a passphrase 2) You have malformed key.

Comment: I am calling ./ssh-keygen to regenerate public key using the -y option . I already have my private key in ssh_host_dsa_key file.